# Please check my proof: If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ if and only if $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$.

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, divisibility, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

Since the divisor sum $\sigma$ is multiplicative and $N = q^k n^2$ is perfect (with $\gcd(q,n)=1$), we obtain
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2q^k n^2.$$

This implies that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n}=\frac{q^k n}{\sigma(q^k)/2}. \tag{*}$$

If $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$, then the **LHS** of Equation **(*)** is an integer.  Hence, the **RHS** is also an integer.  Consequently, we have
$$\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \mid q^k n.$$
But we know that
$$\gcd\Bigg(q^k,\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\Bigg) = \gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k)) = 1.$$
It follows that $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$.

Conversely, if $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$, then the **RHS** of Equation **(*)** is an integer.  Hence, the **LHS** is also an integer.  Hence, we conclude that
$$n \mid \sigma(n^2).$$

We can now state the following proposition:

> **THEOREM:** If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ if and only if $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$.

Here is my:

> **INQUIRY:** Is this argument logically sound?  If this is not correct, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid proof?

Comment: In particular, we obtain
$$\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{n} = \dfrac{q^k n}{\sigma(q^k)/2} = \dfrac{\sigma(n^2) - q^k n}{n - \sigma(q^k)/2},$$
where the last fraction evaluates to
$$\dfrac{0}{0}$$
when $\sigma(n^2) = q^k n$ and $\sigma(q^k)/2 = n$.  This *seems to show* that $\sigma(n^2) = q^k n$ is **untenable**, so that the odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ **cannot be of the form**
$$N = \Bigg(\dfrac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\Bigg)\cdot{n}.$$
Can anybody confirm if this *observation* is **correct**?

Comment: To your inquiry, I think that the answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your confirmation, @mathlove!  May I also have your opinion as to the veracity of my claim in the above comment?