# Does $G \mid I$ and $I \mid H$ still hold if $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is not squarefree, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

This question is an offshoot of [this post #1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4371970) and [this post #2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370402).

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Set
$$G := \gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\bigg)$$
$$H := \gcd\bigg(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigg)$$
$$I := \gcd\bigg(n,\sigma(n^2)\bigg).$$

It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690494) (and fairly easy to prove) that
$$GH = I^2.$$

I claim that:
$$\sigma(q^k)/2 \text{ is squarefree} \implies \Bigg(\bigg(G \mid I\bigg) \land \bigg(I \mid H\bigg)\Bigg).$$

(Note that there are two *unconditional* proofs for $G \mid H$ in post #1.)

---

**PROOF OF CLAIM**

> Suppose that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is **squarefree**.  Since $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n^2$ holds in general, this assumption implies that $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$. From post #2, this is true if and only if $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$.  We then obtain
> $$G = \sigma(q^k)/2$$
> from **Theorem B** in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259745).
> Since
> $$H = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2},$$
> it follows that
> $$I = n.$$
> We get
> $$\dfrac{I}{G} = \dfrac{H}{I} = \dfrac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2},$$
> which is an integer.
> We therefore conclude that $G \mid I$ and $H \mid I$.  (In particular, note that this yields another proof for $G \mid H$, by transitivity.)

**QED**

---

Here is my inquiry:

> Does $G \mid I$ and $I \mid H$ still hold if $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is not squarefree, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

I highly suspect that the answer to my question is **YES**, since we were able to come up with *unconditional* proofs for $G \mid H$ in post #1.

*Alas, this is where I get stuck, as I do not have a proof for $G \mid I$ and $I \mid H$ when $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is not squarefree.*

Comment: $I\mid H$ can be seen as a result of $a\mid b \implies \gcd(a,c) \mid \gcd(b,c)$.  In this way, it has nothing to do with whether something unrelated is square-free.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention, @BrianMoehring!  I did not know about that GCD property.  Do you have any further comments about $G \mid I$?  I know that $G \mid I$ holds **for as long as $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$**, even though $\sigma(q^k)/2$ might not be squarefree.  That being said, please flesh out your last comment as an actual answer so that I can upvote and then accept.  =)

Comment: Blimey!  I just realized that $GH = I^2$ and $I \mid H$ implies $G \mid I$.  Thanks again for the hint, @BrianMoehring!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $I \mid n$ and $n \mid n^2$, it follows that $I \mid n^2$.  Also, by definition $I \mid \sigma(n^2).$  Therefore, by the definitional property of the gcd, $$I \mid \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = H.$$

As you have pointed out, if we additionally assume $GH=I^2$, then this also implies $G \mid I$, so we're finished with no reference to whether $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is squarefree or not.